# Copying old R packages from one linux server and installing them on a new server

Tags: r, linux, unix

I am trying to copy R packages from a directory on one linux server and install them on another. I started out by writing a script that would loop through a list of all the R packages I needed and install them. This worked for a majority of packages, but, since I am forced to utilize R 3.0.3, a significant number of packages are unavailable for this version of R. Meaning that R was trying to install the most recent versions of these specific packages.

I am trying to find a solution that does not involve me having to go through each package, find the version we are running on the old server, then going to CRAN and downloading the archived .tar.gz file.

Ideally, I would like to loop through the directory of R packages, make them all into .tar.gz files, move those files to the new server, and install them like that. However, I ran into the following issue when I tried to "build" one these packages.

```
R CMD build car

Read 1 item
* checking for file ‘car/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘car’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
 ERROR
computing Rd index failed
```

I tried another using `devtools::build('abind')`, but this also failed with the same errors above.

Should I change my approach or is there something missing with what I am doing? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try just copying over the library directory? I'm not exactly sure what you are running to "build" these packages.

Comment: I am in the process of doing what you are suggesting (ie. copying directory). It's just taking a long time. I am unfamiliar with R so a colleague of mine suggested using "build" on packages in the directory with the R packages in order to create .tar.gz files. Then use the .tar.gz files to install those packages. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, doing buid/install would take even longer than just a copy. As long as both machines have the same architecture would compile the code the same, then copying should be all you need.

Comment: I took your advice with copying. This worked fine. Wish I had just come to this solution sooner. Thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach won't work:  `tar.gz` files contain the source for a package, but not all of it is installed when you install a package, so you can't recreate the `tar.gz` file from the installed files.

What might work if you didn't want to work with such an ancient version of R is to use Microsoft's CRAN "time machine" (https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine), but I think it only goes back to R 3.2.3.

Copying the library might work, but binaries of those files are probably linked to system library files at particular locations, so I wouldn't trust it to be reliable.

I think your best option would be to update R to the current release (or maybe 3.5.3, the last patch release of the previous series), then just install current versions of the packages you want.

If this is impossible for some reason, then you're likely to have no choice but installing versions matching the ones you had installed.  At least you can find versions automatically:  the `installed.packages()` function returns a matrix with package name in column `"Package"` and its version in column `"Version"`.  Run that on the old system, then build them on the new system using the `remotes::install_version()` function (which claims to work on R back to 3.0.0, but I bet it hasn't been tested there lately).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up taking Mr.Flick's advice and copying the directory of R packages over to the new server. This worked for me.